# Symfony2 project, Composer not installing package unable to find any version,

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

Hi there am quite new to the world of composer and i'm having problems installing a package into symfony2

The package in question is: https://github.com/gridiron-guru/FantasyDataAPI

My composer.phar looks like the the following:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "gridiron-guru/FantasyDataAPI" : "1.*"
    },
    "repositories": [ {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/gridiron-guru/FantasyDataAPI"
    }],
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

when i run: php composer.phar update
I get the following error.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package gridiron-guru/fantasydataapi could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package
name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

On the Git Repo the only branch is master: with the following tags:

```
1.0.0, 1.1.0,  1.2.0
```

I've tried using dev-master, and the different version numbers.
but to no avail.

Can i fork the repo and then set my own @stable tag for my fork?
How do i reference the new fork?

It could of course be nothing to do with the version, and instead it just cant find the package, although i would think following in my composer.json should address this:

```
"repositories": [ {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/gridiron-guru/FantasyDataAPI"
    }],
```

I'm guessing i can't just download the src and stick it into my vendors dir, as composer needs to generate the autoload and other gubbins.

Any ideas what i can try to get this package into my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the package is wrong (on the official bundle doc also). 
In accordion with the composer.json of the library, the correct name is `"gridiron-guru/fantasy-data-api"`

So, try substitute this row in the `composer.json`:

```
    "gridiron-guru/FantasyDataAPI" : "1.*"
```

with this:

```
    "gridiron-guru/fantasy-data-api" : "1.*"
```

I see you open an issue on the library, can you fix it with an Pull Request for contributing with it?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this, i will add the request to the comment i left, not quite sure how to do a pull, but i will try!

Comment: No problem @DizzyBryanHigh is only a way to contribute to an open source project! fix a doc is a simply task and is usually appreciated by the developer (instead of fix it themselves). Let me know otherwise i will do it for you. But, my solution is ok? is working now?

Comment: yeah worked perfectly!! ypu saved me god knows how much more time!!, i will make the pull request am looking at it now!

Comment: Made my first ever pull request!!

Comment: Great @DizzyBryanHigh! Try linking the issue at your PR

Answer (score 0):

Try publishing your package on Packagist, so you have no more need for:

```
"repositories": [ {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/gridiron-guru/FantasyDataAPI"
}],
```

This way you only need to change the version in composer.json once you release a stable version.

Your composer would look like:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "gridiron-guru/FantasyDataAPI" : "dev-master" // or whatever branch
}
```

Now you only need to run `composer update --prefer-source`.

Also, take a look at this link, helped me when I was trying to do something similar.

http://dimsav.com/blog/9/git-repository-inside-composer-vendors

> The composer option --prefer-source is cloning the package's git repository >inside the vendor directory. To see your repository changes, or commit, simply >chdir to the package's root directory

Comment: thanks will have a read of your link, its not actually my repo so dont think i can add it to packagelist